# code::blocks debugger, "Cannot find the bounds of current function"

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, codeblocks

I want to debug a simple c++ program in code::blocks. "Run to cursor" works, but not "step into" or "next line", these give the message "Cannot find the bounds of current funciton". What I've done:

- The -g compilation option is checked, and the -s one is not
- Latest version of code::blocks just installed
- the right executable path for GDB is set

My setup:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Code::Blocks 13.12
- GCC compiler

The c++ code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("qwe");
    printf("qwe");
    printf("qwe");
    printf("qwe");
    printf("qwe");
    return 0;
}
```

After the "run to line" command, it also says "in ?? () ()", might be worth mentioning.

So, what can I do to have me a funcitoning debugger? What is the underlying problem?

Comment: 'Where did you put your breakpoint?

Comment: When doing "run to cursor", I'd put the cursor say at the third printf, and would get "qweqwe" in console. But subsequent "execute next line"s or "step into"s did not give me more "qwe"s, but instead the error message I wrote about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the issue in the end was **changing the code::blocks compiler executable from "mingw32-g++.exe" to simply "g++.exe" and rebuilding the program.** I finally discovered this by learning to use gdb from command line and seeing that it was, then too, having the same problems with the executable built by code::blocks, but not if I compiled the exact same source code from command with g++. So, that being the only difference, I changed it and it worked. No idea why, tho.

Comment: I had such issue when I was using 32-bit gcc and 64-bit GDB. using 32-bit debugger for 32 bit compiler solved the problem. Maybe your mingw32-g++.exe and g++.exe had different bitness.

Comment: Your solution does not works for me :(  I am  trying to  check the 32/64 bit issue pointed out by Weisskopf